# iterating through values and column names - placing them in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi all i need some help with the below code
Apologies all but I think I will change the question -

the below code works, but What I was trying to do was make it more efficent -

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download("SPY AAPL IOO IXJ", start="2015-01-01", end="2019-04-30")
data
df=data['Adj Close']
returns=data['Adj Close'].pct_change().dropna()
roll_profits = rolling_profits(returns, window).fillna(method='ffill')

list_dict=[]

for column in returns:
    grit = grit_index(returns[column], minperiods)
    ulcer=ulcer_index(returns[column], minperiods)

    row = {'name' : column, 
           'score': grit[-1], 
           'ulcer' : ulcer[-1]
          }
    list_dict.append(row)

print(list_dict)
scoreboard = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list_dict)
print(scoreboard)
```

Notes-

```
grit index

# Define a function 'grit_index'
def grit_index(returns, minperiods):
    cum_rets = cumulative_returns(returns, minperiods).fillna(method='ffill')
    peak_rets = cum_rets.cummax()
    dd = np.log((cum_rets/peak_rets)) ** 2
    ulcer = np.sqrt(dd.expanding(min_periods=minperiods).sum())
    grit = cum_rets * ulcer ** -1
    return grit


input:

    AAPL    IOO IXJ SPY
Date                
2015-01-02  -0.009513   -0.002099   0.002712    -0.000535
2015-01-05  -0.028172   -0.022745   -0.005009   -0.018060
2015-01-06  0.000094    -0.008745   -0.004732   -0.009419
2015-01-07  0.014022    0.008551    0.016184    0.012461
2015-01-08  0.038423    0.019513    0.020904    0.017745

l
```

where returns is a pandas data frame with stock returns as columns.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas in order to improve the above code

many thanks,

Andrew

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I am getting an error on the iteration

Comment: Care to share that error?

Comment: Can you please add sample input and expected output?

Comment: added expected output

Comment: @andrewcz: there is no point in seeing the expected output without actually having the input. Also what is your error?

Comment: hi @Austin added input array

Comment: what is grit_index?

Comment: grit index is a function that takes a pandas array, i think issue has to do with the iteration over nam series

Comment: I couldn't find anything about grit index @andrewcz would you mind sharing the source?

Comment: # Define a function 'grit_index'
def grit_index(returns, minperiods):
    cum_rets = cumulative_returns(returns, minperiods).fillna(method='ffill')
    peak_rets = cum_rets.cummax()
    dd = np.log((cum_rets/peak_rets)) ** 2
    ulcer = np.sqrt(dd.expanding(min_periods=minperiods).sum())
    grit = cum_rets * ulcer ** -1
    return grit

Comment: I am just trying to make the loop component more efficent.

Comment: @Pygirl do you have some ideas on how i can make the code more efficent

Comment: improvement in terms of ?? If you want to improve it in terms of speed then you can use numba (jit) as your grit index function is carrying out mathematical operations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209993/discussion-between-pygirl-and-andrewcz).